# Xcode files (such as view controller.h) aren't showing up.

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, viewcontroller

I just wanted to know why some of my files aren't showing up on the Xcode side bar. I was watching this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNAPy2LqcrY&spfreload=10

video tutorial, and I noticed that my sidebar looked different. I didn't have any of the special files or view controllers. I only have the main.storyboard and viewcontroller.swift

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Xcode window?

Comment: Swift doesn't have separate Header (.h) and Implementation (.m) files like Obj-C. There's just the single .swift file. If you created a basic single-view application then you should also have an AppDelegate.swift. That's all the tutorial shows at the start - AppDelegate, storyboard, and a single ViewController (plus PNG image files he must've imported previously)

Answer (score 0):

It is because he already started. You need to also use Objective-C and not Swift if you want to follow that tutorial. If you look in the description of youtube video, he has links to all the other files and his completed project.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can start over, no problem.